# Overwriting currently playing audio file in embedded linux C

Tags: c, audio, embedded-linux

I've been working on a touchscreen application that shows a cartoon character animation when an NFC tag is detected. I'm using LVGL and it's ffmpeg plugin (which does not currently support audio) for the UI. I'm currently playing audio using

```
system("aplay bear/animalnoise.wav &");
```

Which works fine for when the NFC tag is first detected. I also want to play different animations and sounds when the user interacts with the animation but using aplay like I did above results in an error if an audio file is already being played.

Is there a nicer way of doing this? My first thoughts are getting process IDs and killing any active aplay processes before starting a new one.

Comment: `killall aplay` is certainly one lazy way to do it, which might still be good enough for your purpose. `system` is already a lazy way, after all

Comment: @user253751 What would your approach be for the non-lazy way?

Comment: mine? look up how to use ALSA, look up the wave file format and play sound from my program so my program always has total control of what sound is playing. But sometimes it's okay to be lazy.

Comment: Or just use Python which will help you to mock up the prototype in a few hours. If you need performance, you may rewrite it fully or partially in C or other performant languages.